# Package Building Error - Usage Doesn't Match Function

Tags: r

I am (re)building a package and I have three functions:

```
diffPlot <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("diffPlot")

diffPlot.default <- function(x, y, plotFUN=mean, errFUN=c("ci", "se", "sd"), conf=.95, grp.names=NULL, var.equal=FALSE, paired=FALSE, ...)

diffPlot.formula <- function(formula, plotFUN=mean, errFUN=c("ci", "se", "sd"), conf=.95, grp.names=NULL, var.equal=FALSE, paired=FALSE, ...)
```

The idea here is that a user can pass either x, y format to the function or a formula (i.e., Y ~ X). So the user doesn't ever need to use diffPlot.default or diffPlot.formula. The original diffPlot function will read what the user inputs and pick the appropriate sub-function. This works beautifully when all three functions are in my local workspace.

The problem occurs in the documentation when I am trying to build the package. R does not like the fact that the Usage does not match the function itself. I get the sense that I may need to make the diffPlot() function a Generic, but I don't really know how to do that in the package itself. For what it is worth, the model I am using here is t.test.

Here is what the usage section of the documentation currently looks like:

```
\usage{
diffPlot(x, ...)

## Default Method
diffPlot(x, y, plotFUN=mean, errFUN=c("ci", "se", "sd"), conf=.95, 
  grp.names=NULL, var.equal=FALSE, paired=FALSE, ...)

## Method for class 'formula' 
diffPlot(formula, plotFUN=mean, errFUN=c("ci", "se", "sd"), conf=.95, 
  grp.names=NULL, var.equal=FALSE, paired=FALSE, ...)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try

```
\usage{
   diffPlot(x, ...)
   \method{diffPlot}{formula}(...)
   \method{diffPlot}{default}(...)
}
```

Also refer to: [Guide of Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Documenting-functions)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reach a solution and Thothal's answer got me started. I deleted the manual page for the diffPlot.default and diffPlot.formula functions, retaining just the one for the generic diffPlot function. Here is what it looks like:

```
\name{diffPlot}
\alias{diffPlot}
\alias{diffPlot.default}
\alias{diffPlot.formula}
%- Also NEED an '\alias' for EACH other topic documented here.
\title{
Difference Plot
}
\description{
A function for creating a Difference Plot between two groups.
}
\usage{
diffPlot(x, ...)

## Default Method
\method{diffPlot}{default}(x, y, plotFUN=mean, errFUN=c("ci", "se", "sd"), conf=.95, 
  grp.names=NULL, var.equal=FALSE, paired=FALSE, ...)

## Method for class 'formula' 
\method{diffPlot}{formula}(formula,data, plotFUN=mean, errFUN=c("ci", "se", "sd"), conf=.95, 
  grp.names=NULL, var.equal=FALSE, paired=FALSE, ...)
}
```

Note the use of \alias{} at the top and the use of \method{generic}{class} as suggested by Thothal above.